# How to get access of some graphs /plots in Databricks workflow?

Tags: workflow, databricks, mlflow

I am running a notebook on another notebook using workflow

```
dbutils.notebook.run("python_EDA", 0, {"param1": "var1", "param2": "var2"})
```

In my python_EDA notebook , there are some plots and graphs that are being plotted inside the Notebook job #029309238939093 after running the workflow command .

How to get hold of those since everything is running as a task?
Is it stored in some location ?

I read its stored as MLflow artifacts, how to access these ?

Answer (score 1):

If its the output of MatplotLib then you can save it to the DBFS file system

```
plt.savefig("/dbfs/FileStore/yourimagename.png")
```